# ASP.Net MVC3 external data paging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some code to get my data using a min_row/max_row. I want to pass in the page number rom my menu as well as the paging links.

My main menu has this code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("MyDocuments", "", "Home/MyDocuments/1")
```

My paging links look like this:
(they will be built on the fly from a total record count sent in the ViewBag, not done with that part yet):

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Prev</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="/Home/MyDocuments/1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Home/MyDocuments/2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Home/MyDocuments/3">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Home/MyDocuments/4">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult MyDocuments(int Page)
{
    string min = (Page-1*50).ToString();
    string max = (50 / Page).ToString();
    // mps is a webservice reference 
    Archive docs = mps.GetArchiveArray(LogonTicket, PID, "SortColumn", max, min, "ASC");
    ViewBag.docs = docs;
    return View();
}
```

Now, when I click on the main menu item, I get this error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Page' 
of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult 
MyDocuments(Int32)' in 'MVC3MySite.Controllers.HomeController'.
```

Here is my MapRoutes in Global.asax.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

How do I circumvent this error?

Comment: Answer below is right, or change Action parameter to int id. btw: string min = ((Page-1)*50).ToString()

Comment: Changing the parameter to id resulted in this: `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
@Html.ActionLink("MyDocuments", "", "Home/MyDocuments/1")
```

to

```
@Html.ActionLink("MyDocuments", "MyDocuments","Home",null, new {Page=1})
```

Comment: How would I modify the paging links?

Comment: new{Page=1}, or with id, just 1

Comment: Tried both and got the same error: `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'xxx' of non-nullable...` (either Page or id)

Comment: Ok, had the parameters in the ActionLink reversed, the `new {Page=1}` is the RouteObject which is the next to last parameter. Now works.

Comment: @MiBu: Corrected. Was a in a hurry to get out of the computer and missed it. Thanks.